# Universal Application: two different version for iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I have 2 different version of one program! One for ipad and one for iphone!
I don't care about dupplication of code.
There is an easy and fast method to make a universal application with different file (xib, .m and .h) for specific device (ipad, iphone)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this post : [How to create Universal apps in iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845478/how-to-create-universal-apps-in-iphone-ipad)