# App that works on both IPad and IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I was just wondering if there is a way to create an app in XCode that will detect whether it is being run on and IPhone or and IPad and select different views to suit the platform?

i.e. Pseudo Code

```
//IF CURRENT DEVICE IS IPHONE THEN
//SHOW IPHONE MAIN MENU VIEWCONTROLLER
//ELSEIF CURRENT DEVICE IS IPAD THEN
//SHOW IPAD MAIN MENU VIEWCONTROLLER
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Universal apps in iPhone/iPad? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845478/how-to-create-universal-apps-in-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes
it is called a "Universal App" and there is aTemplate for that project when you set a new "Window Based Application" in xcode.

to test if the device is ipad or iphone you can use this macro:

```
- (BOOL)isDeviceAniPad {
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}
```

shani